# Is this a striker bracket?

Tags: door-frame

I've been trying to find a plastic part for my front door frame. I've attached the pic for you guys to help me understand what that part is actually called. The bottom screw part is broken but it was the same as the top one. I took that part out from the back of the deadbolt striker plate. My door frame is metal type and that plastic part with 2 screwed ready holes help the striker plate to get fastened onto it.
Any help would be really appreciated.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do not know the name, but it seems something is out of adjustment from all the wear on the bottom section.

Comment: That looks to be from a storm door, not a security door--correct?

Comment: @Huesmann No it is for the main front door that has both keyed knob and the deadbolt

Comment: @user3695645 is it plastic?

Comment: Yes the piece itself is plastic

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out the name, its called strike plate retainer or strike boss depending upon which brand's astragal has been installed on your double door. The Endura brand uses the former one and Therma tru brand goes with the latter.

Comment: This site does not run like forum. Please edit your question to add more information.

Comment: @RohitGupta Since, I've already answered my question so there shouldn't be any confusion.